# Spreadsheet (GSheet) formula to check content in a column

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, contains

I have rows with sentences. I need to check if at least one word of each sentence is in the column "Word Check" indicating so in each row. I tried with different formulas with no success. Can you help me please? Thank you.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I found how to:
=IF(REGEXMATCH(H18,TEXTJOIN("|",1,$J$17:J26)),"Yes","")

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

With the rest of the 'Contains' column cleared, you can use this to check any phrase in A2:A against the word list in C2:C. There's only one L in 'Colorful', though, so if there are spelling errors in the Word Check list, they may not be checked correctly against the phrases.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK(A2:A),,
   IF(
    REGEXMATCH(
     A2:A,
     "(?i)"&TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,C2:C)),
    "Yes",)))
```

This will wrap the words with hearts as a delimiter so you can pull exact matches only.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(ISBLANK(H18:H),,
   IF(
    REGEXMATCH(
     REGEXREPLACE(H18:H,"(\w+|\?\.)","♥$1♥"),
     "(?i)"&
     TEXTJOIN(
      "|",
      TRUE,
      REGEXREPLACE(J18:J,"(\w+|\?\.)","♥$1♥"))),
    "Yes",)))
```

Comment: Thank you. How would it be the formula if I want to search for the exact word, for ejample: In the column Word Check the word Mice is needed to be found. But in the sentences finds and asumes that "Micelaneas" is correct also. How can I avoid this, so it finds only "Mice"?

Comment: Check the second formula I just added, @MartinHogg. It'll check for exact matches only.

Comment: Thank you very mutch for your help!

Comment: Sure, how do I mark it as done? I don´t find a "button" or checkmark

Comment: I think there's a checkmark next to the answer that you can hit.